# How can I check if a tab has been created and get the number of tabs currently open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that closes any tab that's created after a certain amount of tabs (for testing I've set it to 1) has already been opened.

I tried using chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener( but I'm not sure why it's not working.

As for checking the number of tabs currently open, I've come across chrome.tabs.query() but I'm not quite sure how to use it.

```
let tabsCount;

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){

    //get number of tabs??

    
    if (tabsCount > 3) {
        window.closeTab()
    }

});
```

Comment: What should it count if there are multiple Chrome windows? Should it only count tabs created by you? If yes, what kind of address do "your" tabs have?

Comment: Any tab opened, for example some websites have advertisements that open up a new tab